# Combining WBS structure types; deliverable oriented and task oriented

Tags: work-breakdown-structure, schedule, deliverables

I'm fairly new to this.  I'm trying to build a WBS for communications equipment installation.  This requires things like licenses, electrical conduit, parts ordering, and outsourcing to other organizations.  It seems that a deliverable oriented WBS would be best for the project, but once I get to the 3rd layer, it seems natural to the components of the deliverable into the tasks necessary to produce the components.  Would a WBS that mixes types in this way work well, or will I run into problems when converting this to a network and project schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A product oriented WBS would have products on top, broken down to its manageable sized components, and then activities below it.  I define the work package to be the lowest level of product; the activities below it enable size estimation.  You should not have any issues scheduling a WBS such as this.

Comment: Is it any problem that some of my lowest level boxes are a mix of tasks and products?

Comment: Not in my opinion